# Who is דישון? Contradiction in 2 verses

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, genealogy, vayishlach

[Breishit 36:21](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=464) list דישון as the son of Se'ir, but verse 25 lists him as the son of Ana, which would make him a grandson of Se'ir. Which is it? Why the contradiction?

Comment: Adding some supporting Hebrew (at least "דישון") would make this question easier to understand quickly, I think.

Comment: Why do you think there is any contradiction - both Seir and Anah had a son whom they named Dishon.

Comment: @GeminiMan - If you can source this and place as answer, that would work well.

Comment: It doesn't need a source, just a pair of glasses :)

Comment: http://dikdukian.weeklyshtikle.com/2008/12/great-confusion.html

Comment: @Double how can one dishon change based on placement in the passuk but not the other? Aren't these types of rules universal?

Comment: @user6591 Pausal forms are notoriously inconsistent actually. Moreover, here the names are transliterations to Hebrew from Edom-ic, so perhaps this pausal from is a derivative of different but similar vowels used in Edom-ic.

Comment: @Double Your first point is noted but that article seems to make it sound like the Dishon was the inconsistency, not the rule of pause. AS to your second point, once the name Is incorporated into Hebrew form, shouldn't it be subject to all Hebrew rules? Like any other foreign name.

Comment: @user6591 Not necessarily. http://dikdukian.weeklyshtikle.com/2008/01/frogs.html?showComment=1229402040000#c6152128007646611703 Like how we say "alumni" not "alumnuses".

Comment: @Double Interesting. You mean that idea from R' Yaakov Kaminetsky? It would be hard to apply that logic to these two dishons as they are both from the same language. But i hear what you are getting at.

Comment: @user6591 They might have been different words in that language with vowels which are similar to Kamatz but one of which is slightly closer to Cholom. So it tended to switch on a pausal form easier. Something like that.

Comment: @Double Ah. Good vort.

Answer (score 4):

According to Da'at Mikra, it's not a contradiction. On verse 36 they write that there were two Dishons and one Dishan. On verse 21 they write that Dishon was a common Horite/[Hurrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurrians) name. There are many examples in Tanach of people whose children shared names with their parents' siblings ([example 1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Chronicles.8.14-18?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi), Elpa'al being the father of Zevadiah I and Bri'ah; [example 2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Chronicles.2.46?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=en)). Moreover, note that Dishon ben Seir is spelled דישון while Dishon ben Ana is spelled דשן. And Dishan is spelled דישן.